# LG G2 GPS works only when screen is off!

Tags: gps, lg-g2

I have the weirdest problem in my LG G2 - the GPS works only when I'm turning my screen OFF!

- Running Kitkat
- Problem reproduces with both Waze and Google Maps Navigation
- Tried a factory reset, didn't help the problem